# How to compare schema of 2 databases with sqlalchemy-diff - Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have Dev and Prod version of Azure SQL(or SQL Server) databases.
I would like to compare schema part of testing.

I read that sqlalchemy-diff could be useful tool. https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-diff/
However I'm getting error from URL. I wonder what needs to be done?

CODE:

```
from pprint import pprint
from sqlalchemydiff import compare

DBURI1 = "Server=my-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my-dev- 
 sql-db;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=No;"

 DBURI2 = "Server=my2-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my2-dev- 
 sql-db;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=No;"

result = compare(DBURI1, DBURI2)
if result.is_match:
    print('Databases are identical')
else:
    print('Databases are different')
pprint(result.errors)
```

ERROR:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'Server=my-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my-dev- 
 sql-db;UID=myuser;PWD=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=No;'
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string

Comment: "Pass through exact Pyodbc string" section applied and got over of this error.